# Add to History Script not working

Tags: bash, history, bash-history

I am trying to add lines from a file to my history, but it just adds the program code! What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash 
HISTFILE=~/.bash_history
set -o history
cat file.txt | while read line
do
  echo "$line"
  history -s $line
done
```

It adds `cat file.txt | while read line; do   echo "$line";   history -s $line; done` instead of each line inside `file.txt` (`foo`,`bar`,`etc`).

Comment: Why don't you just append the lines to `~/.bash_history` directly?

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to do it like that, but probably what you're bumping up against is that (in bash, and many other shells) the RHS of the pipe is executed in a separate subshell - see for example [Why is my variable local one 'while read' loop, but not in another seemingly similar loop?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9954/why-is-my-variable-local-one-while-read-loop-but-not-in-another-seemingly-sim)

Comment: @ByteCommander Actually, appending to `.bash_history` would only affect a new / reset bash, it doesn't change the current history - i.e. can't access the new entries in the current bash session. (FYI, the call to `history` itself is not saved in the history)

Comment: @steeldriver can you think of a better way

Comment: @lol But you can use `history -r` from your current Bash session to re-read the history file and append all new lines from there to your in-memory history buffer.

Answer (score 0):

To me at least, it seems like you could just run `cat file.txt >> $HISTFILE`.  However, as Xen2050 said, it will not update until you restart bash.

Answer (score 0):

First, append your file directly to the history file:

```
cat file.txt >> ~/.bash_history
```

Then, to get the additional lines immediately in your current Bash session, tell it to re-read the history file and append its new lines to the current history list in memory:

```
history -r
```

For more info, type `help history`, `man history` or `man bash`.